# a simple Go simulation - concurrency problem

Tags: go, multidimensional-array, concurrency, channel

I'm a student from Poland, and this semester i started concurrent programming course (Go, Ada and in future some theory and CSP language).Not gonna lie, the Golang seems pretty fun, but i got a bit puzzled by the concurrency, all the waitgroups, mutexes etc. To top it off, I'd call myself a below average programmer for my experience. Basically, my task is to create a simulation which i would describe like that:

- there's a n*m grid
- there can spawn at random moments travelers, up to k travelers, each traveler has unique id (1, 2, 3 and so on up to k)
- at random moment, the traveler can move either up, left, right or down on the grid if the space is free (I decided that free space is 0)
- there's also a camera, that would sometimes print the current state of the grid as well as recent moves (not yet implemented)
- unofficaly, i heard i was supposed to use channels, whatever that means

My idea was to make a struct with id, and coordinates of each traveller, and send their id's to the channel which would indicate a will to move, and then i would randomly choose the direction to move.

I got a bit puzzled by the concurrency - not only if and where should i use the wgs and mutexes but also for example if i do the go func(){} should the loop be inside or outside.I'd greatly appreciate any hints, help or fixes/ideas to fix my code, because currently, as you can guess, it doesn't work properly (for example when camera prints the grid sometimes there's more than k travellers with multiple travellers sharing the same numbers, and sometimes they seem to despawn).Hope everyone's having a good day and i really would appreciate any help :)

```
package main;

import(
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "math/rand"
    //"sync"
    "time"
)

type traveler struct{
    id int;
    x int;
    y int;
}

func main(){

    //command line
    n, err := strconv.Atoi(os.Args[1]);
    m, err := strconv.Atoi(os.Args[2]);
    k, err := strconv.Atoi(os.Args[3]);
    if err != nil{
        panic(err)
        return
    }

    //board
    var grid [][]int;
    grid = make([][]int, n)
    for i:=0; i<n; i++{
        grid[i] = make([]int, m)
    }

    //array of travelers, channel for moves and id
    travelers := make([]traveler, k)
    no_of_travelers := 0;
    move := make(chan int, k);
    id := 1;

    //var wg sync.WaitGroup

    go camera(grid);

    go func() {
        
        for i:=0; i<len(travelers); i++ {   
            if no_of_travelers<k{
                travelers[i] = spawnTraveler(&id,grid);
                no_of_travelers++;
            }
        }
    }()

    go func() {
        for{
            a:= rand.Intn(k);
            sendMoveTraveler(&travelers[a], move);
        }
    }()

    receiveMoveTraveler(travelers, move, grid);

}

func spawnTraveler(id *int, grid [][]int) traveler{
    x:=-1;
    y:=-1;
    for{
        x = rand.Intn(len(grid));
        y = rand.Intn(len(grid));
        if(grid[x][y]==0){
            break;
        }
    }
    t := traveler{id: *id, x: x, y:y};
    grid[x][y] = *id;
    *id++;
    return t;
}


func sendMoveTraveler(t *traveler, move chan int){
        move <- t.id
}

func receiveMoveTraveler(travelers []traveler, move chan int, grid [][]int){
    for{
        id := <- move
        for i:=0; i<len(travelers); i++{
            if travelers[i].id == id{
                direction := rand.Intn(4); //1-left 2-up 3-right 4-down
                switch direction {
                case 0:
                    if travelers[i].x>0 && grid[travelers[i].x-1][travelers[i].y] == 0{
                        grid[travelers[i].x-1][travelers[i].y] = grid[travelers[i].x][travelers[i].y];
                        grid[travelers[i].x][travelers[i].y] = 0;
                        travelers[i].x = travelers[i].x-1;
                        travelers[i].y = travelers[i].y;
                    }
                case 1:
                    if travelers[i].y>0 && grid[travelers[i].x][travelers[i].y-1] == 0{
                        grid[travelers[i].x][travelers[i].y-1] = grid[travelers[i].x][travelers[i].y];
                        grid[travelers[i].x][travelers[i].y] = 0;
                        travelers[i].x = travelers[i].x;
                        travelers[i].y = travelers[i].y-1;
                    }
                case 2:
                    if travelers[i].x<len(grid)-1 && grid[travelers[i].x+1][travelers[i].y] == 0{
                        grid[travelers[i].x+1][travelers[i].y] = grid[travelers[i].x][travelers[i].y];
                        grid[travelers[i].x][travelers[i].y] = 0;
                        travelers[i].x = travelers[i].x+1;
                        travelers[i].y = travelers[i].y;
                    }
                case 3:
                    if travelers[i].y<len(grid)-1 && grid[travelers[i].x][travelers[i].y+1] == 0{
                        grid[travelers[i].x][travelers[i].y+1] = grid[travelers[i].x][travelers[i].y];
                        grid[travelers[i].x][travelers[i].y] = 0;
                        travelers[i].x = travelers[i].x;
                        travelers[i].y = travelers[i].y+1;
                    }
                }
                //fmt.Println("Ściagnalem ruch", travelers[i].id);
            }
        }
    }
}

func camera(grid [][]int){
    for{
    for i:=0; i<len(grid); i++{
        for j:=0; j<len(grid); j++{
            if grid[i][j]!= 0{
                fmt.Printf("%02d ", grid[i][j]);
            } else{
                fmt.Printf("-- ");
            }
        }
        fmt.Println();
    }
    fmt.Println();
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 3);
}
}
```

I got a bit overwhelmed by all of the ideas - wgs, mutexes, atomics etc.

Comment: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: "i got a bit puzzled by the concurrency, all the waitgroups, mutexes etc" https://go.dev/tour/concurrency/1 is pretty good place to start.  Then write a few programs progressively adding additional concepts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- goroutines are lightweight threads if you want to process work concurrently (e.g. taking a camera snapshot & moving a traveler can happen concurrently).
- Channels are used to communicate data between go routines.
- mutex is used to allow goroutines to add a lock on shared data for exclusive data access to avoid race conditions.

That being said:

- Running the camera snapshotting in a goroutine while making a traveler move in another goroutine looks good. The spawning goroutine is unnecessary, you do it only one time so you can just do it in the main goroutine.
- There is no benefit in your case from the channels. You have a goroutine that generates a message and sends it on a channel to another goroutine that will make the move. You can do all of this sequentially in a single goroutine and avoid unnecessary complexity. Channels are useful for a different use-case, but here it's an overkill.
- Since you have two goroutines accessing shared memory, the grid, you need a mutex to avoid race conditions. Whenever one of them runs it must "lock", do the work, then "unlock". The other goroutine will block at the lock step until the one that acquired the lock first unlocks. You can optimize this further with read/write locks (the camera needs a read lock only while the mover goroutine needs a read/write lock)
- If you want to randomize more, you can create a goroutine per traveler.